# Error when using pkgutil to flatten an application bundle into a flat package

Tags: applications, xcode, pkg, open-source, command-line

I have an application bundle that I need to convert to a flattened package.  In my case, the application is a simple bash script that has been bundled into an application using [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).  To flatten the bundle, I used the following command on a machine running macOS 10.15.3...

```
pkgutil --flatten /path/to/application_bundle /path/to/flattened_package
```

When then attempting to run the flattened package, I receive the error, "***You can't open the application because it is not supported on the type of Mac.***"  However, the bundled app runs without any issue.  Any ideas on how to convert a bundled app to a flattened app that will run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pkgutil is the wrong tool for this.  Use ***pkgbuild*** instead.  The syntax is...

```
pkgbuild --root /path/to/application_bundle.app --identifier com.company.application --version 1.0 --install-location /Applications /path/to/flattened_package.pkg
```

Some MDM's require a product archive instead of a flattened package. If that is the case, you can then use ***productbuild*** to create a product archive. The syntax for that is...

```
productbuild --version 1.0 --package /path/to/flattened_package.pkg /path/to/archive.pkg
```